# Phonegap and video files

Tags: ios, video, cordova

Is it possible to search for or get any video file on iOS devices using phonegap?

Currently i use `camera.getPicture` and point it to the `PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM/PHOTOLIBRARY` but that is only showing videos taken with the native iOS camera.